# debugger gem installation issue on windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-debug

Not able to install `debugger` or `ruby-debug19` on a windows 64 bit machine. Have installed Devkit, rubygems and able to install all the other gems except this.

```
ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

gem --version
2.4.1
```

**ERROR :**

```
gem install debugger
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141205-5484-1qgupo8.rb extconf.rb


 checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
    checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
    checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
    checking for vm_core.h... yes
    checking for iseq.h... yes
    checking for insns.inc... yes
    checking for insns_info.inc... yes
    checking for eval_intern.h... yes
    checking for struct iseq_line_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... no
    checking for struct iseq_insn_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... yes
    checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... yes
    creating Makefile

    make  clean
    Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

    make
    Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out

gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
atk (2.2.3 x86-mingw32)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
cairo (1.14.0 x86-mingw32)
columnize (0.8.9)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.7, 1.1.6
gdk_pixbuf2 (2.2.3 x86-mingw32)
glib2 (2.2.3 x86-mingw32)
green_shoes (1.1.374)
gtk2 (2.2.3 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
pango (2.2.3 x86-mingw32)
pkg-config (1.1.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.9.5)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (2.4.5)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some issue with the latest version of RubyGems.

This version has a failure with Ruby 1.9.3 that is causing the error.

Downgrading to version 1.8.x running the following command:

```
gem update --system 1.8.29
```

And then I could install the debugger gem.

```
gem install debugger
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed debugger-1.6.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for debugger-1.6.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-1.6.8...
```

Comment: Might be an obvious step, but after downgrading and installing the debugger, run `gem update --system` to get back to the latest gem version